# Have Total update automatically when different shipping option chosen in Expresso Store

Tags: expresso-store

Is there a way, on the Checkout page, to have the Total automatically update when the buyer chooses a different shipping option (without clicking Update Totals)?

Comment: I did something like that, but the strange thing is that the country is only updated once when i shop as guest, next ajax calls work like they should but the shipping costs aren't calculated anymore. But with the same script as a logged in member it's possible to recalculate on every ajax call? Is there any hidden option to prevent this for guests? Thanks Peter

Comment: To play by the rules of StackExchange you'll need to post this as a new question rather than an answer to an existing question. But by all means link to this thread or any others which are relevant as they help to provide a little extra info.

Answer (score 1):

Since the shipping option and subsequently the total are not updated until the cart is updated you would need to write some javascript that submitted the cart via AJAX and then updated the total accordingly.